# How to lock a database after a particular time from accepting an entry?

Tags: mysql, database

Okay..

I am making a web base application,that will be connected to a sms gateway.
It is basically an attendance app for colleges.

The Attendance will be updated using a sms by the teacher.

Now,the main part-
What I want to do is,the teacher should not be able to correct the attendance after 10minutes of sending the 1st message.i.e,the database should accept a correction or new message for the same class and the same teacher only for 10 minutes after the 1st attendance is recieved in the database.

So only recieving from a particular number should be blocked and also only if it is for the same class...

I hope the question is clear :o

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the sort of thing that you should be enforcing at the DB level, it belongs in your application code.  If you can't connect time, number & class together in your DB, it's time to change your schema.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean McSomething mentioned, this is not done at database level, this is business logic that should be checked just before interacting with a database. The best practice actually is to simply add a column `time_created` and before updating simply check if `NOW()` and `time_created` interval is less than 10 minutes. It's a pretty trivial job, but don't bother trying to do this in database with some stored procedures or other stuff, as it will make your application almost un-debuggable and very sloppy.

Check if there is a row with active number and active class, if there are no - insert, if there are any - check if this row's time_created is greater than 10 minutes ago, if it's not - update, ignore otherwise.